# Error Creating "Large" mediawiki Post

Tags: mediawiki

I recently installed the latest version of mediawiki, and it's more or less running fine. However, whenever I try and post what I might consider a "large" entry, I get an error that says I cannot write to index.php, and so the post fails. I have looked though a lot of the documentation, including the variables settings, and cannot seem to nail down the issue or solution. Is it possible that some of the characters in the post are preventing the post? Or, is there a limit to the amount of text content (characters or total size)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Mark

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, check that `$wgMaxArticleSize` is greater than what you are trying to post.  Even in this case, though, you should get an error message, not an outright failure.  The content of the post is unlikely to cause problems, MediaWiki is UTF-8 safe.

Run through the checklist here as well: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Errors_and_symptoms

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing the text in a text editor and then pasting it into mediawiki in smaller chunks, saving the page then pasting another piece? As long as you don't want to do this too often this could be significantly easier than trying to solve the problem.

Comment: That's not likely to help much -- when you edit a MediaWiki page, the entire page gets loaded and sent back.  There _are_ a few ways around that, but the obvious ones I can think of involve either using the edit API or (ab)using section editing in creative ways.  It's not rocket science, but both of those do take a bit more work and cleverness than simply cutting and pasting.

Comment: But if the problem is specific characters in the post, this would help to figure out which ones are causing the problems. Also, it doesnt seem like he has a problem editing large articles (at least he didnt mention it)